# How to add Progress dialog to fragment until it loads in ViewPager with Adapter of type FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to show progress dialog until fragment loads in ViewPager because it inquires data from network and then renders view of fragment. Right now when when I click on Item in ViewPager it renders fragment but it looks like it is stuck before it renders. Rather i would like to show ProgressDialog when its rendering how to solve it. I want something similar to this. I want this to be on Page Change in ViewPager.

Similar to this. [image]

ON Page change if Fragment is rendering show progress dialog as follows.

Please help. Need a example

Comment: So, you just want to make an existing indeterminate ProgressBar visible or gone... what stops you? No dialog involved in the process.

Comment: Yes basically I have only Fragment class with different instance. Means layout is fixed data changes as it is one Fragment. However to show data I make n/w calls. It takes time. So in that layout should not  get rendered it and it should show progress dialog and once done show fragment layout

Comment: Well, I see no **dialog** in the picture you posted. Do you know that a ProgressBar can be hosted inside a layout without using any dialog? It's just a normal View.

Comment: I want to achieve similar to what i have shown in picture.. I am unable to achieve. Its customized progress dialog shown in picture with animation...

Comment: Yes. It's a very simple custom progressbar (Google) using a **layer list** (Google): there's a **fixed** heart on its background (the first item of the layer list) and an indeterminate progressbar on the second item.

Comment: But how to achieve it while fragment is loading in View pager

Comment: Show the empty (with progressbar) fragment before starting to load, and the filled fragment after? Possibly using an AsyncTask (Google).